# Sample data of salesforce for an trial user

Tags: rest-api, reporting

I want to create some `Reports` and `Dashboards` using salesforce data. For that, I need to log in to salesforce. But, I want to create some sample reports using salesforce sample data first. And then I will get data from that by using REST or SOAP service.

How do I connect to the REST API?

Answer (score 4):

> But,i want to create some sample reports using salesforce sample data first

You can use either the Date Import Wizard...

```
Setup > Data Management > Data Import Wizard
```

... Or the Data Loader

```
Setup > Data Management > Data Loader
```

...to upload a .csv file to Salesforce where the columns represent the fields and the rows represent the records and map the document to the object for which you wish to import data.

You could even use [this site](https://www.mockaroo.com/) to generate a file for you. It may not be perfect, but I've found it quite useful on occasion.

> i don't know how to connect REST API

If you're unsure about this, I highly recommend looking at the [Trailhead Web Integration Services Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices). But the long story short is that you need to create an APEX class, annotated as a `@RestResource` with URL mapping.

A framework for this looks like below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class AccountAPI  {

    @HttpGet
    global static Account show() {

        Account obj;

        return obj;

    }

    @HttpPost
    global static Account create() {

        Account obj;

        return obj;

    }

    @HttpPut
    global static Account updateObject() {

        Account obj;

        return obj;

    }

    @HttpDelete
    global static void remove() {

    }

}
```

You then need to annotate (as shown above) with `@HttpGet`/`@HttpPut`/`@HttpPost` etc... which you can then call from a URL like below:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/something
```

You'd just need to:

- Pass in the Http Method you're using which will execute the respective method
- Pass in the body (e.g. if you're posting or inserting data, what fields should map to what value)
- Pass in any parameters.

Again, the Trail explains it much better than this, but this gives you a basic overview as to how to do this.

**Edit**

I should clarify that in the URLMapping, where I've used an asterisk (*), it's a wild card. So the URL could end with an Account ID, for example. In which case the URL might look like:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/0010Y000002dGNO
```